# How to convert binary to decimal with long integer?

Tags: java, binary, type-conversion

I want to convert fraction binary number to decimal .
`11010010011101010011`

For this i am getting error

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "11010010011101010011"`

Comment: Could you show us your code?

Answer (score 0):

Please check below 2 method. it may be useful for you.

We can do it assigning binary value in String

```
String binary = "11010010011101010011";
int decimal = Integer.parseInt(binary,2);
System.out.println("Decimal==>" + decimal);
```

else we can use wrapper class to convert it

```
Integer decimalInt=Integer.valueOf("11010010011101010011",2);
System.out.println("Decimal==>" + decimalInt.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
long n = Long.parseLong("11010010011101010011", 2);
```

Should work. As these are 32 bits, and a representation for a in fact negative `int` do not use parseInt or so.

Also make sure there is no garbage. An UTF-8 text file might start with a BOM char, zero-width space, invisible. Removing BOMs could be done as:

```
s = s.replace("\uFEFF", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

P.S. my English isn't good but I'll try to explain bellow.

1. First, you have to reverse String.
2. Then, from first to end, get the element and multiply by `2^place`.

Here is the code:

```
public static void convertToDecimal(String binaryNumber)
{
  String reverse = new StringBuffer(binaryNumber).reverse().toString();
  long decimal=0;
  for(int i=0;i<reverse.length();i++){
    char c = reverse.charAt(i);
    int k=c-'0';
    decimal=decimal+k*(long)Math.pow(2, i); 
  }
  System.out.println(decimal);
}
```